# Java For Loop Error on array with objects

Tags: java

I am new to Java and working on a small learning project but I am stuck. I am trying to figure out why the for loop is generating Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at MyApp.main(MyApp.java:26). Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? I greatly appreciate the assistance!

```
// Create array of toddlers
babyMikeyToddler[] toddlercollection = new babyMikeyToddler[4];

toddlercollection[0] =new babyMikeyToddler("Baby Mikey",10,2);
toddlercollection[1] =new babyMikeyToddler("Baby Mikey",10,2);
toddlercollection[2] =new babyMikeyToddler("Baby Mikey",10,2);

for(int i =0; i < toddlercollection.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(toddlercollection[i].getName());
}

    }

}
```

Comment: `toddlercollection[3]` is `null`.

Comment: I'm new here, but this seems like a question we should downvote. Is that the case?

Comment: @Nasser Probably not. It's a basic error, but the question is reasonably clear and well-phrased.

Comment: @user2757868 In the future, please post the entire stack trace; just that little bit doesn't tell us much about where the problem is.

Comment: Did you, you know, try to debug this code?  Did you step through it?  Did you examine your output and compare it to what you had expected to see?  I'm just curious why your first reflex upon getting an error here was to come to StackOverflow ... it seems that there should have been plenty of tools and plenty of info already available or at hand that could have helped you figure this out on your own.

Comment: @Reimeus I wasn't sure, because as chrylis and scottb stated, it is a basic error, but I asked because, as you mentioned, OP stated he is new to the language, and I didn't want to do that. Anyway, thanks, I upvoted the answer

Comment: You have an array with 4 "slots" and you only fill 3 of them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop will reach toddlercollection[3] (since 3 is less then the array length), and that is null.  So when you call `toddlercollection[i].getName()`, it's trying to call `getName()` on `null`, and that causes an exception.

Comment: Thank you. I feel so stupid! I'm a PHP Programmer in real life lol but its much more forgiving and doesn't require you to set the array size.

Comment: @user2757868 If you have a list of something but don't know how many you're going to end up with, use a `List` instead; `ArrayList` if you have a stable list and need random access, `LinkedList` if you're going to be adding and removing elements a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to JacobM's answer, `toddlercollection.length` denotes the number of 'slots' the array is having, not the number of assignments you have made to the the array.

To solve you problem either allocate only 3 slots in you array

```
babyMikeyToddler[] toddlercollection = new babyMikeyToddler[3];
```

or fill all the slots

```
toddlercollection[3] =new babyMikeyToddler("Baby Mikey",10,2);
```

or have a counter for the filled slots and iterate using it

```
int c = 0;
toddlercollection[c++] =new babyMikeyToddler("Baby Mikey",10,2);
toddlercollection[c++] =new babyMikeyToddler("Baby Mikey",10,2);
toddlercollection[c++] =new babyMikeyToddler("Baby Mikey",10,2);
for(int i =0; i < c; i++) { ... }
```

or better yet use a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
List<babyMikeyToddler> toddlercollection = new ArrayList<>();
toddlercollection.add(new babyMikeyToddler("Baby Mikey",10,2));
toddlercollection.add(new babyMikeyToddler("Baby Mikey",10,2));
toddlercollection.add(new babyMikeyToddler("Baby Mikey",10,2));
for(int i =0; i < toddlercollection.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(toddlercollection[i].getName());
}

// using enhanced for loop
for(babyMikeyToddler elem : toddlercollection) {
    System.out.println(elem.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please stick to Java naming conventions otherwise code is really confusing. Class names must start with capital letters( like `BabyMikeyToddler`) and variables/functions name must be in camel case(like `toddlerCollection` ).

Whenever you get a NPE it is because you are performing operations on variable that is NULL. In your case you are using for loop to print values so why not use it to assign values?(After all each element in toddlercollection array has same data). So you could do

```
for(int i =0; i < toddlercollection.length; i++)
{
    toddlercollection[i] =new babyMikeyToddler("Baby Mikey",10,2);
}
```

You are getting NPE in your for loop because toddlercollection[3] is not assigned an object and is null. Yet you are trying to print it's value. Other that what I suggested above always check for variable being NULL before operating on it.

Eg.

```
    for(int i =0; i < toddlercollection.length; i++)
    {
        if(toddlercollection[i].getName() != null)
        {
            System.out.println(toddlercollection[i].getName());
        }

    }
```